# Why does my phone connect as a camera in Photos.app

Tags: finder, photos.app, android

When I connect my Android phone via usbc it is visible under the 'Devices' header in the sidebar of photos.app and I can import images from it.

This would indicate to me that the phone is connected correctly, but if I open Finder I cannot see the device listed anywhere.

Is it possible that my mac is somehow registering the device as a camera and blocking file import? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

**The iPhone is not a USB thumb drive.**

What version of macOS and iOS do you have?

If it is recent enough and you click on the iPhone in the Finder sidebar it will give you sync (and other) controls like you used to have in iTunes.

But (again) the iPhone file system is not generally accessible via the Finder only via various apps like Photos/iTunes, etc.  And there it offers only management of specific kinds of files (EG music, photos).

Apple does it this way to (presumably) make the phone easier to use for non technical users who don't know or care what a file is. They just want to play a song, view their pictures or read the message their friend just sent.

Comment: FWIW, the OP does not appear to be using an iPhone.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that the device is Android